# Symfony - Don't have form_error when removing required attr from source code

Tags: php, symfony, assert, required

I just noticed in my symfony project that if I have an entity that has a **non-nullable field**, and that in the formType I make sure that the field **is required**.

So in the rendering of the page, if I do "inspect the element" and I manually **remove the "required" attribute from the field**, well **I can validate**, and in this case I will have a doctrinal error instead of staying on the form page with a simple validation error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'titre'
>   ne peut être vide (null)

However, I use `{{form_row(form.field)}}` in my Twig file, so I should have the **form_error** too.

Does this mean that for all my entities, I have to add `@Assert\NotNull` each time to avoid this problem? It seems far-fetched even if it is not managed automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `@Assert\NotNull` annotations is indeed the proper way to go if you want server-side validation.

Alternatively, you can add the constraint in the form type if you don't want to touch your entities:

```
'required' => true,
'constraints' => new Assert\NotNull(),
```

Now, if you really want auto-mapping of doctrine types into Symfony validation, read the following article:
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-automatic-validation

There are some issues with that feature which made the Symfony team disable it by default. Solution is to uncomment the following lines in `config/packages/validator.yaml`:

```
        #auto_mapping:
        #    App\Entity\: []
```

Symfony 4.4 also ships with two new annotations (`@Assert\EnableAutoMapping` and `@Assert\DisableAutoMapping`) which allow you to enable/disable that feature on per-class/field basis